# Убрать php поставить слеш

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу найти решение.

Требуется для всех файлов директории `/forum/` с расширением php убрать php и поставить слеш.

То есть на файлы `https://www.сайт.ru/forum/forum12/topic2401.php`
редиректить с url `https://www.сайт.ru/forum/forum12/topic2401/`
Нашел решения для всего сайта, но тогда все файлы редиректятся, а мне нужно только в этой директории /forum/. Физически директории нет.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не вполне корректно формулируете задачу. Может, Вам нужно "редиректить" в обратном направлении, чтобы url `/topic2401/` обслуживался файлом `topic2401.php`? Либо url же `/topic2401.php` (при отсутствии файла) редиректить на `/topic2401` который обслуживает другой rewriterule?

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Прежний движок форума выдавал адрес темы с расширением php, то есть topic2404.php новый же может только topic2401/ именно cj слеш вместо .php В остальном урл не изменился, поэтому ищу решения по перезаписи урл в .htaccess и именно для директории /forum/. В данный момент там стандартный .htaccess для wordpress. Постоянные ссылки /%postname%/ только с такой работает плагин форума.

Comment: Возможно ли  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([-\w]+/)*?[-\w]+)(/?)$ $1.php [L]                                                                 
Применить только директории sait.ru/forum/

Comment: Скорее, что-то вроде `^forum/([\w-]+/)*([\w-]+/?)$`. Вам просто нужно добавить необходимый префикс(`forum`) для правила.